# Numpy element-wise dot product without loop and memory error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, gpgpu

I am dealing with a simple question with numpy. I have two lists of matrices - say `A,B` - encoded as 3D arrays with shapes `(n,p,q)` and `(n,q,r)` respectively.

I want to compute their element-wise dot product, that is a 3D-array `C` such that `C[i,j,l] = sum A[i,j,:] B[i,:,l]`. This is very simple mathematically speaking, but here are the rules I must follow:

1) I must only use numpy functions (`dot`, `tensordot`, `einsum`, etc.): no loop & cie. This is because I want this to work on my gpu (with cupy) and loops are awful on it. I want all operations to be made on the current device.

2) Since my data can be quite large, typically `A` and `B` already take few dozens of Mb in memory, I don't want to build any items with bigger shapes than `(n,p,q),(n,q,r),(n,p,r)` (no intermediate 4D arrays must be store).

For example, the solution I have found [there](https://jameshensman.wordpress.com/2010/06/14/multiple-matrix-multiplication-in-numpy/) , that is using:

```
C = np.sum(np.transpose(A,(0,2,1)).reshape(n,p,q,1)*B.reshape(n,q,1,r),-3)
```

is correct mathematically speaking, but implies the intermediate creation of a (n,p,q,r) array which is too big for my purpose.

I had similar trouble with something like

```
C = np.einsum('ipq,iqr->ipr',A,B)
```

I don't know what are the underlying operations & constructions, but it always leads to a memory error.

On the other hand, something a bit naive like:

```
C = np.array([A[i].dot(B[i]) for i in range(n)])
```

seems ok in terms of memory but is not efficient on my gpu: the list is build on the CPU it seems, and re-allocating it to gpu is slow (if there is a cupy-friendly way to write that, it would be a nice solution!)

Thank you for your help !

Comment: What are the typical values of `n,p,q,r ` in your actual use case?

Comment: Wish it could work with `n =~ 5000`, and say `p=q=r = 50` (but the more the better). For example, a `cp.array()` with shape `(5000,50,50)` takes 112 Mb on my gpu (over 2 Gb), which is ok, but if I had to store a `(5000,50,50,50)` array...

Comment: I would think `np.einsum('ipq,iqr->ipr',A,B)` would work best for those shapes. Is it giving memory error with it? If so, why not slice into chunks?

Comment: Actually `einsum` on gpu gives memory error truly easily... Even with `n = 1000` and `p=q=r=50` it does not work (while at least the other solution i mentioned do work with so few data). What do you mean by slicing things into chunks ? Whatsoever, I am pretty sure it can be done without storing bigger arrays... I mean, `np.dot` does not create a `(p,q,r)` array, so why should I do that for element-wise operation ?...

Comment: One more thing would be using a traditional loop after initializing output array, `C` and then use the `np.dot` method.

Comment: That could be a solution, but I am disappointed that I cannot do that without a loop... Furthermore, isn't filling an array with a loop unefficient on a gpu ? I mean, writing `for i in range(n): c[i] = a[i].dot(b[i])` works but does not seem to be the way one should deal with gpu, am I wrong ?

Comment: I am not sure about right or wrong when it comes to performance. In here, you have `np,dot`, which is super efficient. So, even if you loop with it, it won't be too bad, unless the loop count is too big. On the slicing thing, I meant, using something like `np.einsum('ipq,iqr->ipr',A[0:50],B[0:50])`, `np.einsum('ipq,iqr->ipr',A[50:100],B[50:100])`  and so on, of course storing the results in a loop. It's in chunks, so a smaller loop count. I would go with the dot-loopy one though.

Comment: I get your point, but I mean, using a `5000` loop to perform `50,50 x 50,50` dot product may not be the best way to do it. Furthermore, performance is at the core of my current work (i.e. my final conclusion aims to be "we did it X times faster than previously"), so I don't want to have a bottleneck in my code, even if it works.
I will deal with these temporary solutions but I remain open to fully-vectorized solutions.

Comment: I'm confused about the GPU part. AFAIK numpy does not have a GPU backend. What library are you using?

Comment: @HannesOvrén, `cupy` provides much of the numpy API but has a GPU backend.

Comment: `einsum` gets memory errors because it iterates, in C code, over a large variable space.  In this case it's the `ipqr` 4d space (5000*50*50*50).  It doesn't do any more calculations than needed, but also doesn't break the calculation into 5000 (50x50) calculations.

Comment: @BiRico, Ah, I missed the "(using cupy)" bit in the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want [`numpy.matmul`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html) ([cupy version here](https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/reference/generated/cupy.matmul.html?highlight=matmul_matmul)). `matmul` is a "broadcasting" matrix multiply.

I think folks have known that the `numpy.dot` semantics are wonky and that a broadcasting matrix multiply was needed, but there wasn't much momentum to introduce the change until python got the [`@`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/) operator. I don't see `dot` going anywhere, but I suspect the better semantics and the ease of  doing `A @ B` will mean that `dot` will fall out of favor as folks discover the new function and operator.

Comment: Why the down vote? This is exactly what the OP is asking for :)

Comment: Dunno. Maybe they thought it wasn't translatable to cupy?

Comment: Hey ! That's perfectly what I was looking for. On prelim test it did not raised any memory error and seems quite easy to use for my purpose. I don't know why I did not get this solution by myself (and why other links I read mention twisted solutions). Thank you very much ! (And sry, I don't know who downvoted you, seems pretty weird).

Answer (score 0):

The iterative method that you seek to avoid might not be so bad.  Consider, for example, these timings:

```
In [51]: A = np.ones((100,10,10))
In [52]: timeit np.array([A[i].dot(A[i]) for i in range(A.shape[0])])
439 µs ± 1.35 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [53]: timeit np.einsum('ipq,iqr->ipr',A,A)
428 µs ± 170 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [54]: timeit A@A
426 µs ± 54.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

For this case all three take about the same time.

But I double the later dimensions, the iterative approach is actually faster:

```
In [55]: A = np.ones((100,20,20))
In [56]: timeit np.array([A[i].dot(A[i]) for i in range(A.shape[0])])
702 µs ± 1.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [57]: timeit np.einsum('ipq,iqr->ipr',A,A)
1.89 ms ± 1.63 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
In [58]: timeit A@A
1.89 ms ± 490 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

The same pattern holds when I change the 20 to 30 and 40.  I'm mildly surprised that `matmul` times match `einsum` so closely.

I suppose I could try pushing these to memory limits.  I don't have a fancy backend to test that aspect.

A modest number of iterations over a large problem isn't so horrible, once you take into account memory management issues.  The thing you want avoid, in numpy, is many iterations over a simple task.

Comment: I think the issue is that OP is trying to use `cupy` and in that context each iteration is not simply a memory copy but also a gpu-memory -> main-memory copy which is more expensive, especially when relative to the speedups you want to see from gpu operations.

Comment: Yes that's exactly the point :) I want to avoid gpu-->cpu travels :)

Comment: For your information: I tried the loop implementation vs the matmul one on a GPU (Tesla P100), and it appears that matmul goes about 1000 times faster for n = 5000, p,q,r = 80,100,120 , so yep, the loop is costly there !

Weirdly enough, when run on cpu (with numpy), matmul appears to be a bit slower than the loop... (like 4 sec vs 1sec).